# Почему все объекты не выводятся из for в if?

Tags: php, json, api

```
$filename = ENGINE_DIR . '/inc/mhblock/serials.txt';
$json = file_put_contents($filename, file_get_contents('http://moonwalk.cc/api/serials_foreign.json?api_token=d10a8f4368bc3a6e26b11477ad939da1'));
$file_json = file_get_contents(ENGINE_DIR . '/inc/mhblock/serials.txt');
$data = json_decode($file_json,true);
$datac = $data['report']['total_count'];
$sql = $db->query("SELECT id, title, kp_id_movie, xfields FROM " . PREFIX . "_post");
for ($i=0; $i <= $datac; ++$i) { 
    while ($rowes = $db->get_row($sql)){
        if($data['report']['serials'][$i]['kinopoisk_id'] == (int)$rowes['kp_id_movie']){
            echo '<tr class="danger">
            <th>' . ++$i . '</th>
            <th>' . $rowes['title'] . '</th>
            <th>' . $rowes['kp_id_movie'] . '</th>
            <th>' . $data['report']['serials'][$i]['translator'] . '</th>
            <th><a href=\"{$config['admin_path']}?mod=editnews&action=editnews&id={$rowes['id']}\" target=\"_blank\" data-original-title=\"Перейти к редактированию\" class=\"status-info tip\" ><i class=\"icon-edit\"></a></th>';
        }
    }
}
```

В if выводит только один объект из [0] с совпадением из БД [кинопоиск_ид]
А мне нужно, чтобы они выводили некоторые обьекты с совпадением.

Как это реализовать?

Допустим из API лежит [0] и его содержимое кинопоиска: 471742

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title_ru] => 1001 ночь / Тысяча и одна ночь
            [title_en] => 1001 gece / BinBir Gece
            [year] => 2006
            [token] => a196f79599bde0294241a7062c43dec5
            [type] => serial
            [kinopoisk_id] => 471742
            [world_art_id] => 
            [translator] => одноголосый закадровый
            [translator_id] => 65
            [iframe_url] => http://moonwalk.cc/serial/a196f79599bde0294241a7062c43dec5/iframe
            [seasons_count] => 1
            [episodes_count] => 90
            [category] => 
            [block] => Array
                (
                    [blocked_at] => 
                    [block_ru] => 
                    [block_ua] => 
                )

        )
```

После этого из БД нашло совпадение равну API объекту.
На сайте выводит только один :-(

```
int(471742) == int(471742)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// достаём все id
$kinopoiskIds = array_map(function($e) {
  return str_replace(',', '', $e['kinopoisk_id']);
}, $data['report']['serials'])

// выполняем запрос с in
$result = $db->query("SELECT id, title, kp_id_movie, xfields FROM " . PREFIX . "_post where kp_id_movie in (" . implode(',', $kinopoiskIds) . ")");

// ваш цикл
while($result) { ... }
```

Comment: Неплохо, спасибо за подсказку! 
А там выдает ошибку в var_dump($result)
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
Как быть?

Comment: нашел ошибки, есть некоторые объекты из БД выдают NULL и даже из API, и при этом там запятые ид_кп,,ид_кп,ид_кп,ид_кп,,ид_кп!
Как исправить это?

Comment: @АртурКарволеев отредактировал

Comment: Из базы данных тоже также выходят некоторые NULL и при этом ,, двойные запятые выходят в некоторых местах( 
Ошибка такая же.

Comment: @АртурКарволеев отредактировал пробуй все запятые удалить