# Уникализация многомерного массива (нужного объекта) Иным словом удаление дубликатов

Tags: php, json, api

Есть примерный массив из API:

```
[1932] => Array
            (
                [title_ru] => Игра престолов
                [title_en] => Game of Thrones
                [year] => 2011
                [token] => 9258550a799e3ea8a07a3da405df58e0
                [type] => serial
                [kinopoisk_id] => 464963
                [world_art_id] => 
                [translator] => IdeaFilm
                [translator_id] => 57
                [iframe_url] => http://moonwalk.cc/serial/9258550a799e3ea8a07a3da405df58e0/iframe
                [seasons_count] => 2
                [episodes_count] => 17
                [category] => 
                [block] => Array
                    (
                        [blocked_at] => 2017-07-25 15:40:11
                        [block_ru] => 1
                        [block_ua] => 
                    )

            )

        [1933] => Array
            (
                [title_ru] => Игра престолов
                [title_en] => Game of Thrones
                [year] => 2011
                [token] => 666c343b49c7fb076efdcd0fcd3b572f
                [type] => serial
                [kinopoisk_id] => 464963
                [world_art_id] => 
                [translator] => Субтитры
                [translator_id] => 20
                [iframe_url] => http://moonwalk.cc/serial/666c343b49c7fb076efdcd0fcd3b572f/iframe
                [seasons_count] => 7
                [episodes_count] => 67
                [category] => 
                [block] => Array
                    (
                        [blocked_at] => 2017-07-25 15:41:31
                        [block_ru] => 1
                        [block_ua] => 
                    )

            )

        [1934] => Array
            (
                [title_ru] => Игра престолов
                [title_en] => Game of Thrones
                [year] => 2011
                [token] => e086c6617dc40d74c46a395c1edca9eb
                [type] => serial
                [kinopoisk_id] => 464963
                [world_art_id] => 
                [translator] => Gears Media
                [translator_id] => 81
                [iframe_url] => http://moonwalk.cc/serial/e086c6617dc40d74c46a395c1edca9eb/iframe
                [seasons_count] => 2
                [episodes_count] => 17
                [category] => 
                [block] => Array
                    (
                        [blocked_at] => 2017-07-25 15:42:13
                        [block_ru] => 1
                        [block_ua] => 
                    )

            )
```

**Вопрос**: Как вывести уникальные массивы с неповторяющимися значениями по имени `[kinopoisk_id]`?

Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
$input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $data['report']['serials'][тут циферки]['kinopoisk_id'])));
```

Но ничего не выходит. И через `For` не помогает, так как выводит ошибку:

> Warning: array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array in  Warning:
>   array_unique() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

---

**Update** :

```
$filename = 'engine/serials.txt';

$json = file_put_contents($filename, file_get_contents('http://moonwalk.cc/api/serials_foreign.json?api_token=d10a8f4368bc3a6e26b11477ad939da1'));
$file_json = file_get_contents('http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/serials.txt');
$data = json_decode($file_json,true);
$datac = $data['report']['total_count'];
for ($i=1; $i <= $datac; ++$i) { 
    echo $data['report']['serials'][$i]['kinopoisk_id'] . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: лимит вопросов исчерпался на другом аккаунте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/755966/191482 ? :)

Comment: Лимитов нет, вот и поэтому избегаюсь лимитов, так как на вопросы не отвечают, ведь 0 ответов и поэтому приходится заново задавать на разных аккаунтов, ведь шанс будет.

Comment: .....Нельзя так

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем полный вопрос. Например, не понятно, какой вариант при повторах вас интересует, первый или наоборот последний?
Как вариант предлагаю создать новый массив с ключами kinopoisk_id

```
$new_arr = [];
foreach ($you_arr as $item){
    $new_arr[$item['kinopoisk_id']] = $item;
}
print_r($new_arr);
```

Вывести можно любым способом, например, так:

```
<?php foreach ($new_arr as $item): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?=$item['title_ru']?></td>
    <td><?=$item['title_en']?></td>
    <td><?=$item['year']?></td>
    <td><?=$item['type']?></td>
    <td><?=$item['seasons_count']?> из <?=$item['episodes_count']?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Дополнение, попробуйте организовать цикл так:

```
for ($i=0; $i < $datac; $i++) { 
    if (!empty($arr[$data['report']['serials'][$i]['kinopoisk_id']]))
        next;
    $arr[$data['report']['serials'][$i]['kinopoisk_id']] = 1;
    echo $data['report']['serials'][$i]['kinopoisk_id'] . '<br>';
}
```